# WHERE IN statement returns Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

those lines work great and are giving me right output:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `scores` WHERE id IN ('tim', 'scrat')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

BUT, if I want to replace `('tim', 'scrat')` with some variable that I'm first creating with info I'm getting from another column:

```
$query = "SELECT friendsids FROM `scores` WHERE id='tom'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$friendsids = ($row[0]);
echo ($friendsids); // this correctly logs: tim,scrat

// now the same as above, but using $friendsids:
$query = "SELECT * FROM `scores` WHERE id IN ($friendsids)";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

I keep getting the error

```
Query failed: Unknown column 'tim' in 'where clause'
```

so it seems like the WHERE operation does put the $friendsids into pieces, but somehow not recognize them correctly?

not sure if it's relevant, my table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `scores` (
`id` VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
`score` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT ‘0’,
`friendsids` VARCHAR(1000)
)
TYPE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: You're missing the quotes. Your current query looks like: `WHERE id IN (tim,scrat)` but it *needs* to look like: `WHERE id IN ('tim','scrat')`.

Comment: Could you print the `$friendsids` variable?

Comment: Thanks Amal! That totally was the problem and it's solved :) I ended up adding the scores already into the column of friendslist, so I won't have to do any string operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hitting the database twice and running in the described troubles you could simply use this query made up from your first ones:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `scores`
WHERE
    id IN (
        SELECT
            friendsids
        FROM
            `scores`
        WHERE
           id='tom')
```

Otherwise you need to add quotes to your first result, but I think this saves time and nerves.

Comment: Hey Trieber, thanks for the tip. I tried it but it's not finding any scores and it seems like the problem is that the second SELECT statement (the one in brackets) is giving me a Resource back, rather than actually this: ('tim','scrat'). How would you solve that?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I wasn't aware that you save a comma separated list of friends. You should normalize this to a separate table with one row for each relation between two users (id, friend_id). Then the proposed approach will work.

Comment: oh, I see - na I think the separate table will be a little more work. Thanks anyway for the tip!

Comment: actually, I think I'm coming back to your approach, and I'm trying to create a separate table with id->friend_id relations. But now where I'm stuck: I would get a lot of rows with duplicated entries, because every id comes up more than once (for each friend_id). Any ideas on that?

Comment: That's right and correct. Every user id may show up many times in each of your both columns (additionally I would suggest a third, the id of the row itself for several reasons). But as long as you take care not to insert really duplicate rows (same user_id and same friend_id) that IS correct. So avoid "sam" -> "joe" and "sam" -> "joe", but every other constellation is ok.

Comment: finally got that working - thanks a lot for the tip again! You saved me a lot of troubles :)

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was what you needed you may vote up and finally accept it.

Comment: It's simple. Use the arrows and the hook/check mark left to the answer. Read this great tutorial here: http://stackoverflow.com/about. I'm not sure, perhaps this would require registration.

Comment: ah, cool - just did. I can't vote though - requires 15 reputations